# Photos with arabic names return 404 not found error in URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have some photos with arabic names like `12345-الجزيرة-الجزيرة-الجزيرة-الجزيرة-12345.jpg` in a `photos` folder and the browser returns not found error for  `http://domain.com/photos/12345-الجزيرة-الجزيرة-الجزيرة-الجزيرة-12345.jpg`. Could you please let me know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set the default encoding of the apache web server?

Open the /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and set:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

Open .htaccess and set:

```
IndexOptions +Charset=UTF-8
```